# "view has expired" message in Primefaces Demo

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, view, primefaces, viewexpiredexception

In [primefaces demo page](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase), if you wait enough time for the session to expire without doing anything and then click an ajax button you get the error message:

[image: View Has Expired Message From primefaces showcase]

I'm wondering how this mechanism is implemented. Is it possible that they used [Fullajaxexceptionhandler](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/exceptionhandlers/FullAjaxExceptionHandler) of `omni faces` as an addition to primefaces?

Comment: Either you can use FullAjaxExceptionHandler or you can implement such thing yourself. They have their own ExceptionHandling now http://fractalsoft.net/primeext-showcase-mojarra/sections/ajaxerrorhandler/ajaxerrorhandlerDefaultBehavior.jsf;jsessionid=70rrm3k0y89m1n5c6sv3yh43l

Comment: Is it a pure trivia-hunting question or you ask how to implement something like that yourself?

Comment: I couldn't find how primefaces doing this, an encapsulated module or a  workaround. now i see that it's an encapsulated and tested solution which is better then implementing one for myself.